# wordpress 404 not working properly

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

I have a Wordpress site with permalinks set to /%category%/%postname%.html. When I visit to a non-existing page, let say, example.com/non-existing-post, Wordpress 301-redirects to homepage instead of showing the 404.php page, which is inside the theme's package. Below is the htaccess code;

```
AuthName "protect"
AuthUserFile "/home/sitename/.htpasswds/public_html/passwd"
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/sitename/public_html/
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

When I tried to disable custom permalink structures, it returns a error 404 but not with 404.php page that I preferred(normal Apache error, I guess).

There have been a lot of similar discussions about this "bug", please see the links below. All of them not seem to be resolved. :(

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/404-pages-not-working-1

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/404-pages-not-working

What's causing Wordpress automatically 301-redirect a page that is supposed to show 404 error?

UPDATE(Feb 21, 2013) - Problem's still persistent. I think it's a bug in the wordpress core that involves in "pretty permalinks" redirections.

Still I'd like to solve this problem since I've got a handful of Wordpress sites that have this and I think other people are experiencing the same bug in their sites.

Comment: To help server to find the 404 page, add the following line to your `.htaccess` file: `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404`

Comment: @jeromeM, Thanks for your answer, but still it did not solve the problem. I think something within the wordpress core that's doing redirections with "pretty permalinks" is causing the error.

Comment: A different way to solve the problem with this topic http://wordpress.org/support/topic/problems-running-under-phpfastcgi

Comment: @jeromeM I've read that yesterday. Aside from the fact that the fix involves editing the Wordpress core(which I think is not recommended), the mentioned code is already deprecated in the current version of Wordpress(the post you cited above was posted in Wordpress forum 6 years ago). Appreciate your input though

Comment: sorry for the old link.

Comment: Any luck with this, @user2090302? I too had found those previous links, and they're from long ago, so not even sure if they are the real issue anymore.

Comment: @snipe. Nope, didn't solve this issue yet. Still looking